# Git clone: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none

Tags: git, ssl, github, ssl-certificate

I was setting up the edge tpu dev board following the tutorial (https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#run-pycoral), and was able to connect to the board's shell via MDT. when I tried to git clone the repo, I saw this error message:

```
mendel@mocha-zebra:~$ git clone https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral.git
Cloning into 'pycoral'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

Can someone help? Thanks!

What I did / have tried:

**1. update CA certificates**

```
mendel@mocha-zebra:~$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20190110).
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (1.8.2.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
mendel@mocha-zebra:~$ sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

**2. fetch certificates**

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername git.mycompany.com -connect git.mycompany.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p'  > git-mycompany-com.pem
```

**3. add to certificate list**

```
cat git-mycompany-com.pem | sudo tee -a /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

**4. Reset the clock**

Now `date` outputs correct date and time

**5. disable SSL certification validation**

```
git config --global http.sslverify false
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
```

After I disabled the SSL certification validation, running git clone gave a different error message:

```
mendel@mocha-zebra:~$ git clone https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral.git
Cloning into 'pycoral'...
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
   redirect: https://charter.guestinternet.com/?UI=8587f8ed-8341-4b82-a120-d257b139c9c4&api_domain=https://secure.11os.com&UI=040d98&NI=0050e8040d98&UIP=24.97.110.215&MA=7CD95CB25273&RN=50&PORT=50&ZONE=Unauth Zone&RAD=yes&PP=no&PMS=no&SIP=172.20.9.93&OS=https://github.com%2Fgoogle-coral%2Fpycoral.git%2Finfo%2Frefs%3Fservice%3Dgit-upload-pack
```

Answer (score 0):

`charter.guestinternet.com` means some kind of Community Solutions WiFi feature, where you need to authenticate first to a portal, *before* being able to access internet.

Try and go to that portal first, to authenticate you.
Then try your `git clone` again.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to go to that portal using nmtui?

Comment: @Kaka4869 Not sure, for captive portals, `ip route` is generally used: https://askubuntu.com/a/1014372/5470, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89705/7490. Also: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#Captive_portals